# Count and Display the List of Value of <select> ACF plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I create a select field called "Country" with the option:

- Malaysia
- Indonesia
- Singapore
- Thailand
- Myanmar

And I try to show the total of the country registered on select field to my front end.

Expected result:
We connect "5" countries in Asia.

I have tried:

```
<?php
    $number = count(get_field_objects('country'));
?>

<p>We connect <?php echo country; ?> Countries in Asia</p>
```

And I've got nothing.

Comment: `get_field_objects` returns _all_ fields saved on a specific post - and takes a _post id_ as first parameter. Did you confuse it with `get_field_object` (singular)?

Comment: Both functions return an array - which is something you can not output via `echo` to begin with (that will only ever get you the _word_ "Array".) Make a `var_dump` of the value first, if you don't know where in there the values you are actually looking for, are stored.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check my below solution. I have also used same solution on one of my website. You need to use "get_field_object" function instead of "get_field_objects".

```
$countries = get_field_object('country');
echo count($countries['choices']);
```

Comment: The result is 0, by the way, where 'choices' come from?

Comment: Choices is for select field.

Comment: Are you using flexible content or normal field?

Comment: I see. Have no idea if it's flexible or normal.